# Menu won't slide back up once user go to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm creating a web app that has a custom responsive menu. It's just your basic three list-item menu dropdown. When user clicks "hamburger" icon, it slides down. When they click on the "X", it slides up.

The problem having is that when the user clicks the "hamburger" icon in the mobile menu's closed state and then they click another link on the page outside of the mobile menu, the menu stays in its open/slid down state and becomes unusable unless the user reloads the page.

What do I need to put in my JS function or my CSS to prevent this behavior? I appreciate the help.

The code:
HTML:

```
<nav class="home-header-content__nav--menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
    <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav class="home-header-content__nav--mobile-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (only the relevant stuff):

```
.home-header-content__nav--menu {
   @media (max-width: $site-screen__iphone5s--landscape + 1px) {
     display: none;
   }
 }
.home-header-content__nav--mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  .fa {
     font-size: 28px;
     &:hover {
        color: $site-color__secondary;
        @include transition(0.2s ease-in);
        cursor: pointer;
     }
  }
  .fa-times {
     display: none;
  }
  ul {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: $site-color__secondary;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  a {
    color: $site-color__white;
    &:hover {
        color: $site-color__secondary--darker;

    }
  }
   @media (max-width: $site-screen__iphone5s--landscape) {
     display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function responsiveHomeMenu(){
// Store content nodes in DOM
var $menuIcon = $('.home-header-content__nav--mobile-menu .fa');
var $menuList = $('.home-header-content__nav--mobile-menu ul');

// Hide menu links by default
$menuList.hide();

// Toggle menu with icon
$menuIcon.on("click", function(e){
    $menuIcon.toggle();
    $menuList.slideToggle(300);
    $(document).off("click",function(){
        $menuList.toggle();
    })
});
});
```

Comment: Do you want the menu to hide when something else on the page is clicked or not? Or you want it to stay open and remain clickable?

Comment: I'd try to move the variables and `$menuList.hide();` outside the function. It should hide the menu on `$(document).ready`

Comment: @A_funs I want it to slide back up once something else has been clicked on. I also want it to hide again once a new page has loaded. I'm having trouble with the latter. Everytime I click the menu icon to slide down the mobile menu and go to a new page afterward (without clicking it again to close it), the menu stays slid down on the new page and becomes useless as well (can't click it to slide back up). It also does even when I click it to slide back up right before I go to a new page.

Comment: @Nordenheim I did take your advice and implemented this without success unfortunately. It still doesn't reset after I go to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    // Toggle menu with icon
menuIcon.on("click", function(e){
    menuIcon.slideToggle();
    menuList.slideToggle(300);

});
$(document).on("click",function(){
        menuList.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: I did take your advice and implemented this without success unfortunately. It still doesn't reset after I go to a new page.